# Format string date 'd/m/y' to 'dd/mm/yyyy' in ionic / angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

i having issues to convert a string date from 'd/m/y' to 'dd/mm/yyyy' for example: i want to convert  26/8/19 to 26/08/2019.

i tryied with:

```html
let date = 26/8/19
var d = new Date(date); 
console.log(d)
```

result: invalid date.

tryied with angular pipe locate, with date pipe {{date | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'}}
and it doesnt even show me the date.

used some other data convert pipes but in result i get other dates for example '26/08/1950', etc.

any help is welcome.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't use quotes around the date (which is being evaluated as 26 divided by 8 divided by 19), but your later example does. Which way is it in your actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is quite specific about the formatting of strings that can be passed as dates, and the format `26/8/19` is not included.  Even if there was a way to be sure that order of days/months/years in the string, a number such as `19` could be referring to any year ending in 19 (e.g. 1819, 1919, 2019 etc.)

For more information about string formatting see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

For your specific case I would recommend splitting the string and using the values to reconstruct the date

```
const d = "26/8/19"
const args = d.split('/')
const day = args[0]
const month = args[1]
const year = "20"+args[2]
const date = new Date(year+'/'+month+'/'+day)
```